# Trying to save a canvas with a paint script

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am wondering how to save the canvas drawn with this canvas paint script I found. I need to save the canvas as a `.png`.

Comment: On the server or locally?

Comment: On the server not locally.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toDataURL` method of the canvas object and post/put it on the server - with form or with ajax. The returned string is base 64-encoded version of the image.

More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement

I use jQuery in the example. The `$("#canvas_element_id")[0]` is the same as `document.getElementById("canvas_element_id")`.

```
function save() {
    var image_data = $("#canvas_element_id")[0].getDataURL();

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/url/to/save/script.php",
        data: {
            img: image_data
            // pass anything else you want as JSON
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(res) {
            // display status message - success or failure
        }
    });
}
```

On the server side (/url/to/save/script.php):

```
$img = $_POST['img'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$img = base64_decode($img);

// now $img contains image binary data (can be saved on disk) - save it, manipulate it... etc.
// You can use fopen, fwrite or their equivalent to save in file
```

Its PHP since I have done it there, but the mechanism is the same anywhere else... ASP.NET, Python, etc.